# MYSQL MULTIPLE FOREAIGN KEYS getting Cannot add foreign key constraint

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

```
CREATE TABLE customer (    
    customer_id INT NOT NULL,     
    last_name VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,      
    first_name VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,      
    street_address VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,      
    apt_number INT NULL,      
    city VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,      
    state VARCHAR(2) NOT NULL,      
    zip_code INT NULL,      
    home_phone VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL,      
    mobile_phone VARCHAR(12) NULL,      
    other_phone VARCHAR(12) NULL,      
    PRIMARY KEY(customer_id)    
);    

CREATE TABLE donut_order(      
    donut_order_id INT NOT NULL,      
    customer_id INT NOT NULL,      
    order_date DATE NOT NULL,      
    special_handling_notes VARCHAR(255) NULL,      
    PRIMARY KEY(donut_order_id),      
    FOREIGN KEY (customer_id)      
    REFERENCES customer (customer_id)      
    ON DELETE CASCADE      
    ON UPDATE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE donut_order_item (      
    donut_order_id INT NOT NULL,      
    donut_id INT NOT NULL,      
    qty INT NOT NULL,     
    PRIMARY KEY(donut_order_ID, donut_id),      
    UNIQUE INDEX(donut_id, donut_order_id),      
    CONSTRAINT donut_order FOREIGN KEY (donut_order_id)     
    REFERENCES donut_order (donut_order_id)      
    ON DELETE RESTRICT      
    ON UPDATE RESTRICT,

    CONSTRAINT donut FOREIGN KEY (donut_id)      
    REFERENCES donut (donut_id)      
    ON DELETE RESTRICT  
    ON UPDATE RESTRICT
);
```

Comment: Hi can you edit your question  for clarification

Answer (score 0):

Try to use user Interface Instead and it could help you to solve this problem.
like this one:

[image]

Comment: I wish I could, However I am restricted to using SQL FIDDLE